# Internet (both wifi and LAN) Stop working after some time

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom, dns

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell N4050. But there is a problem with my internet. It first works fine. But after sometime about 3 to 4 min, it stop working.

I tried to ping with server, default gateway and google, it ping with DNS but doesn't ping with the other 2. If i disconnect from wifi or LAN and connect again, it start working without any problem, But after sometime, same thing happen.

Before this, I installed 14.04, but there were some problem. I have windows 8 in parallel and the internet is working fine on it.

I have following network controller:

```
mhassan@mhassan:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

And some time, packet misses when I ping - like 4 sent but 3 recieved.

Can any body help me to solve this problem?

Comment: It is solved now.
There was problem in my Internet setting. The setting of subnet which i was using perhaps has another ip address as i was using. So i wrote just DNS server in setting and after that i check in which subnet i got ip address. So i change ny subnet and ip address. So now both wifi and eth are working fine....

Answer (score 0):

Solution/fix and it's a permanent.

Type in command line:

```
sudo modprobe ath5k nohwcrypt
sudo sh -c "echo 'options ath5k nohwcrypt' >/etc/modprobe.d/custom-wireless.conf"
```

Comment: Explain why does this help.

Comment: I have no idea why it happens, just know entering the code fix it

Comment: I got slow speeds after entering the fix for "Wifi cutting out" so I then entered the following codes to fix "the slow speeds"

`$ sudo rmmod -f iwlagn`

`$ sudo modprobe iwlagn 11n_disable=1`

`$ sudo su`

`# echo "options iwlagn 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlagn-disable11n.conf`

`$ sudo su`

`# echo "#disable ipv6" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

`# echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

`# echo "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`

`# echo "net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf`